# Local NPM modules not installing correctly

Tags: node.js, npm

Local NPM modules are no longer installing correctly for me in my projects **node_modules** dir. This has just started happening.

I set up a **test** dir with a **package.json**:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

Then ran this command:

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

This is what I get in my **node_modules** dir:

[image]

Opening the **grunt** dir you can see there’s no **node_modules**:

[image]

Some of the NPM modules that appear in the root are what appears to be NPM modules belonging to the **grunt** NPM module, and some I have no idea where they are coming from? E.g. **abbrev**, **esprima**, **graceful-fs**, etc.

I used to get this:

```
project
│
└───node_modules
|   │
|   └───grunt
|
└───package.json
```

I’ve tried completely removing Node.js and NPM from my machine (Mac OS X 10.10.5) following these [instructions](https://hungred.com/how-to/completely-removing-nodejs-npm/). Then reinstalling it outside of Homebrew (where it was previously installed) which didn’t change anything. Then completely removing Node.js and NPM again and reinstalling it *with* Homebrew but this time I applied [this](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689). Again this didn’t fix anything.

Not sure what’s going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. When you install grunt, npm recursively installs all its dependencies. These may be put to grunt/node_modules or may be put on the same level as grunt (directly in the top level node_modules). Both these options will work, which is because of how node works: if grunt requires some package (for example, colors) and node does not find it in grunt's node_modules directory, node tries to find the package in the parent's dir, then in grandparents dir and so on.

Out of these two options, older npm versions prefer the first option, newer versions prefer second option (i.e. more flat dependency tree), which is exactly your case.

In your case, packages such as 'async' or 'colors' are grunt dependencies (check out its package.json), 'abbrev' is not direct dependency of grunt, but  probably it is dependency of some other dependency.

More reading:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe

https://github.com/alexanderGugel/ied

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap

Comment: OK thanks for the explanation. I guess I don't understand this part though: _“'abbrev' is not direct dependency of grunt, but probably it is dependency of some other dependency.”_ if I only have **grunt** then what can be using these dependencies? This just feels broken to me.

Comment: No, its definitely not broken :) grunt depends on 'nopt' package which depends on 'abbrev' package. Since the modern npm is more flat-dependency-tree oriented, you ended up having all these dependencies in one directory. OTOH, with older npm, you would end up having 'nopt' located in ./node_modules/grunt/nopt and 'abbrev' in ./node_modules/grunt/nopt/node_modules/abbrev